# Hibernate Search using FlaotBridge for range queries

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

Im using hibernate search version 5.10.x and i would like to search over a flaot ranges.

My field is:

```
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = FloatBridge.class)
private Float minusPunkte = -1f;
```

After generate lucene index, the generate index is like expected a value between -1.0 and 150.0

In Luke:

[image]

To search over a range of values i use:

```
        Float lowerTermFloat = null,
                upperTermFloat = null;
        try {
            lowerTermFloat = StringUtils.isEmpty(lowerTerm) ? null : Float.parseFloat(lowerTerm);
            upperTermFloat = StringUtils.isEmpty(upperTerm) ? null : Float.parseFloat(upperTerm);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new HibernateSearcheParseException();
        }
        return NumericRangeQuery.newFloatRange(path, 4, lowerTermFloat, upperTermFloat, includeLower, includeUpper);
```

This generate search string for lucene:

```
+totalPunkte:[120.0 TO *}
```

if i would like to have all entries greater than 120

But in the result there are also values smaller than 120:

[image]

It looks, that its searching over string values, and not over float values!

But why does the FloatBridge not generate comparebles string values from float value? What do i wrong? Do i need my own Bridge for comparing float values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FloatBridge` is a legacy bridge, from way back when Lucene didn't have any support for numeric values. See its javadoc:

```java
/**
 * Bridge a {@link Float} to a {@link String}.
 *
 * @see NumericFieldBridge#FLOAT_FIELD_BRIDGE
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
```

To index floats as floats, and not as string, simply don't specify a bridge at all. Hibernate Search will do the right thing by default.

So, your mapping becomes:

```java
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
private Float minusPunkte = -1f;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the Bridge and recreate the index again. But now i get the exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000233: The specified query '+totalPunkte:[120.0 TO 120.0]' contains a string based sub query which targets the numeric encoded field(s) 'totalPunkte'. Check your query or try limiting the targeted entities.

Comment: Ah, i changed now the type of my query to an booleanQuery. Now it does work without any exception! Thanks for your help...